# Why F4 Phantom II didn't have an cannon?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, fighter, bomber, f-4

Question is simple but seriously ? Who would design a FIGHTER bomber without an cannon ? What was the crazy reason they didn't added an cannon to it ? (Also My CPU is Athlon X2 II 250.... If only I had an Phantom CPU instead of an Athlon series...)

Comment: The reason why they want to do it it is because it's heavy.(900 pounds for the gun, magazine and feeding, and full ammunation) and takes a lot of space. The reason why thought they could live without it is because missiles were thought to be the solver bullet. Just like some phones doesn't have ear phone jacks any more, some computers does not have keyboards, some cars wont have a steering wheel soon. Innovations always seem crazy for its time but time has and will prove some of them ingenious while others indeed insane.

Comment: [A cool article about the F-4](https://www.airspacemag.com/military-aviation/what-couldnt-f-4-phantom-do-180953944/)

Comment: Later models **did** have a cannon. Although the early models didn't have a canon (under the assumption they weren't needed anymore after the invention of AA missiles), it was soon found to be a mistake (learned the hard way in the Vietnam War), an internal cannon (M61) was introduced in the E model (and all subsequent ones)

Comment: The earlier versions of the F4 used by the US Navy and USAF could be equipped with gun pods housing 20mm cannon and 7.62mm machine guns. These were used quite extensively in Vietnam although mainly for ground attack work.

Comment: 20mm gun pods used by the F4 in USAF service included the SUU16/A and SUU23/A pods with the M61 cannon, using an air turbine and gas operation respectively to power the gun, while the US Navy used the Mk4 gun pod housing the twin barreled Mk 11 revolver cannon with a rate of fire adjustable up to 4200 RPM.